# SGD weight space updates with asynchronous training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, ensemble-learning

I'm looking at creative ways to speed up training time for my neural nets and also maybe reducing vanishing gradient.  I was considering breaking up the net onto different nodes, using classifiers on each node as backprop "boosters", and then stacking the nodes on top of each other with sparse connections between each node (as many as I can get away with without ethernet network saturation making it pointless).  If I do this, I am uncertain if I have to maintain some kind of state between nodes and train synchronously on the same example (probably defeats the purpose of speeding up the process), OR I can simply train on the same data but asynchronously.  I think I can, and the weight space can still be updated and propagated down my sparse connections between nodes even if they are training on different examples, but uncertain.  Can someone confirm this is possible or explain why not?

Comment: You'd be better ask such theoretical questions on https://stats.stackexchange.com or https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. The most probable outcome is that you will find highly suboptimal solution. Dozens of researchers have done it before you - use the cumulated knowledge, this is what science is about.
http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/papers/pdcn08.pdf
http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~gmagoulas/Distributed_computing_neural.pdf

Comment: Hmm I would have to disagree that this "wheel" exists.  The answer below points out an approach that's close, but there is pretty wide consensus that this problem remains unsolved due to ethernet network constraint.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do what you suggest, however it is a formidable amount of work for one person to undertake. The most recent example that I'm aware of is the "DistBelief" framework, developed by a large research/engineering team at Google -- see the 2012 NIPS paper at http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/large_deep_networks_nips2012.pdf.

Briefly, the DistBelief approach partitions the units in a neural network so that each worker machine in a cluster is responsible for some disjoint subset of the overall architecture. Ideally the partitions are chosen to minimize the amount of cross-machine communication required (i.e., a min-cut through the network graph).

Workers perform computations locally for their part of the network, and then send updates to the other workers as needed for links that cross machine boundaries.

Parameter updates are handled by a separate "parameter server." The workers send gradient computations to the parameter server, and periodically receive updated parameter values from the server.

The entire setup runs asynchronously and works pretty well. Due to the async nature of the computations, the parameter values for a given computation might be "stale," but they're usually not too far off. And the speedup is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was aware of this approach but this is a great reminder that I need to dig deeper into the details.  Based on overviews I have listened to of this approach though they still haven't quite solved the high dimensional data space bottleneck, although they are probably as close as anyone. .  Point taken on the degree of difficulty as well!  There are a lot of ways to skin the cat, and the work effort will definitely factor into which approaches to apply in practice.  Anyway failing at this is more fun than succeeding at the other stuff I'm working on right now!  Thanks again.